# split text in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

**select split_part(comment, ':', 3) as comment ....**

-- comments look like: comment = '2020-10-05 11:59: comment's body'

-- if there is a ':' in the comment, I will get a part of the comment. I need to get all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a very formatted string.  So, just use `substr()`:

```
select substr(comment, 19)
```

If the first part is not so well formatted, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace('2020-10-05 11:59: comment''s body', '^[^:]+:[^:]+: ', '')
```